# Adding a different, specific item to the first x items in a for loop without using enumerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm having a bit of an issue working out the best / most efficient way of adding a specific symbol/text/word to the first 4 items in my list.

```
for list_item in list["rows"][:6]:
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']

    full_list.append('{} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(list_name, list_score))
```

For example, my current output would be:

```
Gold team with a score of 23.22
Yellow team with a score of 18.90
Red team with a score of 15.05
Blue team with a score of 13.29
Green team with a score of 10.93
Teal team with a score of 10.30
```

I want to make the output similar to:

```
 Gold team with a score of 23.22
 Yellow team with a score of 18.90
 Red team with a score of 15.05
 Blue team with a score of 13.29
Green team with a score of 10.93
Teal team with a score of 10.30
```

The order of the emojis in this example would always be the same so

```
emoji_list= ["", "", "", ""]
```

I know I could do it with enumerate fairly easily but there must be a better way of doing it?

I don't want to be doing things like:

```
for i, list_item in enumerate(list["rows"][:6]):
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']

    full_list.append('{} {} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(emoji_list[i], list_name, list_score))
```

Then having to worry about the fact the list index will end up out of range... having to modify it so it looks like:

```
for i, list_item in enumerate(list["rows"][:6]):
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']

    if i < len(emoji_list):
        full_list.append('{} {} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(emoji_list[i], list_name, list_score))
    else:
        full_list.append('{} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(list_name, list_score))
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach? Looks fine!

Comment: @user5173426 nothing, other than there must be a quicker and more efficient way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator from the emoji list and then use the `next` function to fetch its values sequentially:

```
emojis = iter(emoji_list)
for list_item in list["rows"][:6]:
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']
    full_list.append('{} {} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(next(emojis, ''), list_name, list_score))
```

or if you don't want the leading space for ranks without an emoji, you can use a reversed emoji list and pop it as you iterate, and use a ternary operator to decide what to output:

```
emojis = emoji_list[::-1]
for list_item in list["rows"][:6]:
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']
    full_list.append('{}{} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(emojis.pop() + ' ' if emojis else '', list_name, list_score))
```

Comment: Problem with that is the 5th and 6th items would have a space at the start of them. It would work if I removed the space between the two `{}` and added a space to the end of each emoji.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip_longest.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
for list_item, emoji in zip_longest(list["rows"][:6], emoji_list):
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']

    space = ' ' if emoji else ''
    full_list.append('{}{}{} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(emoji, space, list_name, list_score))
```

If you want to add default emoji to rest of list, use `fillvalue=` in `zip_longest`.

Comment: @Ryflex, (I have no reputation to add comments). Answer @blhsing is close enough IMO. You can add `emoji = next(emojis, '')` and next `space = ...` from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x and 3.x provides `zip()` function to map two lists into a single iterator. Although `zip()` truncates to the shortest list size, the **itertools** module provides `izip_longest()' to pad to the longest length.

The following snippet gives you the exact output.

```py
for emoji, list_item in izip_longest(emoji_list,list["rows"][:6]):
    list_name = get_team_name(list_item)
    list_score = list_item['list_score']

    full_list.append('{} {} team with a score of {:.2f}'.format(emoji or "", list_name, list_score))
```

P.S: `emoji or ""` is used to prevent `format()` from printing None.

In python 3.x, **itertools** provides `zip_longest()` instead of `izip_longest`.

Also  is is suggested otherwise to use the list keyword as a variable name. This will overwrite the `list()` function with the variable storing the team details (as in `list["rows"]`).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use unpacking with `lstrip()`:

```
emoji_list= ["", "", "", ""]
list_name = ["Gold", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Teal"]

for i in range(6):
    print("{} {} team with...".format(str(*emoji_list[i:i+1]), list_name[i]).lstrip())
```

Note that slicing `list` is way to get an empty list without worrying about index error

Which prints:

```
 Gold team with...
 Yellow team with...
 Red team with...
 Blue team with...
Green team with...
Teal team with...
```